# GUI for managing translations in i18n JSON files

Tags: javascript, translation, json, localization

We use JSON files in the standard i18n format like:

**locale-en_US.json**

```
{
   "hello.world": "Hello World!"
}
```

**locale-de_DE.json**

```
{
   "hello.world": "Hallo Welt!"
}
```

Does anyone know a good GUI for managing those translations? I am looking for something like [RESX Resource Manager (c#/.NET)](http://resxresourcemanager.codeplex.com/) where you can see all your translations and which ones are missing in the other files.

Comment: Any luck with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using BabelEdit.
I faced the same issue and decided to use this for my non-technical team members.

https://www.codeandweb.com/babeledit

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/63864)